# Compare strings by their written representation - is it possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, string

For example I have a column that contains string (in English - "A", "B" ) "AB1234" and I'd like to compare it to the string "AB1234" (in Russian "A", "B"  ), for Example.
Is there any built-in function to achieve this?

The best way I found is to use Translate func where i enumerate all needed symbols.

Comment: +1, nice reminder that the world isn't all english ;-)

Comment: @DCookie: we in Russia use only those 12 letters that are common to both Latin and Cyrillic alphabets for the license plates. It's quite a common problem for automobile databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a function `LOOKS LIKE`.

Unfortunately there is no such function in `SQL`.

Instead, you can create a function-based index that casts every string to a common denominator using `TRANSLATE`, and search for the string:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_transliterate ON (TRANSLATE(UPPER(str), 'АВЕКМНОРСТУХ', 'AВEKMHOPCTYX'))

SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   TRANSLATE(UPPER(str), 'АВЕКМНОРСТУХ', 'AВEKMHOPCTYX') = TRANSLATE(UPPER('весна на танке'), 'АВЕКМНОРСТУХ', 'AВEKMHOPCTYX')
```